# Disable prompt on ionic cordova prepare?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to automate in jenkins the build of my ionic cordova app.

The command I run in jenkins are:

```
yarn
ionic cordova prepare
```

On the ionic cordova prepare, it is prompting some questions if I want to update the version of some plugin

> Local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova has an update available (1.2.1
>   => 1.3.0 )! Would you like to install it? (Y/n)

Is there any flag or parameter to pass pass to the prepare to disable the prompt or say no to the update?

I didn't find any information in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution from the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html#flags)

The flag `--no-interactive` does the trick.

`--interactive / --no-interactive`: Switch between interactive (default) and non-interactive mode. In non-interactive mode, the spinner and all prompts are disabled (useful for CI/CD servers).

It will basically answer no to all the update questions, very convenient.

Comment: Is there a way to make it answer yes by default?

Answer (score 16):

I you ever want to say YES instead of NO you can use:
`--no-interactive --confirm`